# To mock a provider

Tags: angularjs, sinon, angular-mock

I have a module that in its config uses a provider that I need to mock.

provider itself has `register` function that takes 2 arguments and `$get` function that returns an object, but that's not really important (I think) since I'd be mocking it anyway. Just in case [here's the entire provider](https://gist.github.com/f75fd5cf37f29fea1e2b.git)

module uses the provider like this:

```
angular.module('replenishment').config(configureReplenishmentColumnDef);

configureReplenishmentColumnDef.$inject = ['columnDefProvider'];
function configureReplenishmentColumnDef(columnDefProvider) {
   let config = {
      matchWhen: ((schema)=> _.get(schema, 'format') === 'replenishment'),
      $get: replenishmentColDef
   };

   columnDefProvider.register(config);
}

replenishmentColDef.$inject = ['$q', 'schema', 'medData'];
function replenishmentColDef($q, schema, medData) { 
  ....
}
```

I started putting together a spec like this *(our tests written in CoffeeScript)*

```
describe 'replenishment-module', ->

  columnDefProvider = undefined

  beforeEach ->
    module ($provide)->
      $provide.provider 'columnDef', ->
         @.register = sinon.spy()
         @.$get = sinon.spy()
         return // had to put an explicit return here, as @DTing suggested    

    module 'replenishment'

    inject ->
```

Now I don't know how to properly mock provider's methods. Can you guys please show me, maybe I need to use stubs instead of spies.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding explict returns like this, I think you are getting a malformed function:

```
describe 'replenishment-module', ->

  columnDefProvider = undefined

  beforeEach ->
    module ($provide)->
      $provide.provider 'columnDef', ->
        @.register = sinon.spy()
        @.$get = sinon.spy()
        return        

    module 'replenishment'

    inject ->
```

I think this is what your javascript equivalent looks like:

```
beforeEach(function() {
  module(function($provide) {
    return $provide.provider('columnDef', function() {
      this.register = sinon.spy();
      return this.$get = sinon.spy();
    });
  });
```

which would make it so your Provider columnDef doesn't have a $get factory method:

```js
function Something() {
  return this.get = function() {
    console.log("get");
  };
}

var something = new Something();
something.get();
```

Comment: oh no, that's not it... it's just bad copy/pasting

Comment: Hmm thought of something you might want to try.

Comment: with explicit return I don't see 'must define $get factory method' error anymore, but I'm getting a different sort of error. I need to correctly use sinon here, instead of using a spy I may need to have a stub that accepts 2 arguments (for register function)

Comment: this is the error I'm seeing:
  
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got Object
 http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.16/ng/areq?p0=fn&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20Object

Comment: Sorry I'm not familiar with using sinon.